# Resetting a variable increases it instead of resetting it - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a game of Pong using tkinter as a small project. I have written the game and it works fully. However I have encountered a weird bug where upon the game ending, when one player reaches a score of 3, when the game is restarted the velocity of the ball appears to double, and this happens every time the game is reset. the startgame function should set the variable dx (x movement of the ball) to 2 when it is called, so I am not sure why it appears to get faster by 2 everytime, as there are no additions present.
I have posted the whole code block below and am completely lost as to why this happens, any help would be much appreciated!

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

#size of window
w = 600
h = 400
sw = root.winfo_screenwidth()
sh = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (sw - w)/2
y = (sh - h)/2
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

#playing frame, with Canvas inside
canvframe = Frame(relief=SUNKEN, width=600, height = 350, background="black")
canvframe.pack()

canv = Canvas(canvframe, background="black", width=600, height = 350)
canv.pack(fill=NONE)

# Objects in canvas           
ball = canv.create_oval(300,160,310,170, outline="white", fill="white", width=2, tags=('ball'))
paddle1 = canv.create_rectangle(0,200,10,120, outline="white", fill="white", width=2, tags=('paddle1'))
paddle2 = canv.create_rectangle(590,200,600,120, outline="white", fill="white", width=2)

#Paddle movement      
def moveUp1(event):
    canv.move(paddle1, 0, -10)        
    pass
def moveUp2(event):
    canv.move(paddle2, 0, -10)        
    pass
def moveDown1(event):
    canv.move(paddle1, 0, 10)        
    pass
def moveDown2(event):
    canv.move(paddle2, 0, 10)        
    pass 

#InitialVelocity
dx = 0
dy = 0

#initial score
Player1score = 0
Player2score = 0

#start game - what happens when you push start button (reset velocity and scores)
def startgame():
    global dy, dx, Player1score, Player2score
    canv.coords(paddle1, 0,200,10,120)
    canv.coords(paddle2, 590,200,600,120)
    dx = 2
    dy = 0
    Player1score = 0
    Player2score = 0
    Player1scoreLabel.configure(text="Score: "+ str(Player1score))
    Player2scoreLabel.configure(text="Score: "+ str(Player2score))
    moveBall()

#Ball Movement
def moveBall():
    global dy, dx, Player1score, Player2score
#    to make ball bounce off paddle 1
    if canv.coords(ball)[0]<=canv.coords(paddle1)[2] and canv.coords(paddle1)[1]<= canv.coords(ball)[1] <= canv.coords(paddle1)[3]:        
        dx = -dx
        if canv.coords(paddle1)[1] <= canv.coords(ball)[1] <= (int((canv.coords(paddle1)[1] + canv.coords(paddle1)[3])) / 2 ):
            dy -=1
            canv.move(ball, dx, dy)
        elif (int(canv.coords(paddle1)[1] + canv.coords(paddle1)[3]) / 2 ) <= canv.coords(ball)[3] <= canv.coords(paddle1)[3]:
            dy += 1
            canv.move(ball, dx, dy)
        else:
            canv.move(ball, dx, dy)
#    to make ball bounce off paddle 2
    elif canv.coords(ball)[2]>=canv.coords(paddle2)[0] and canv.coords(paddle2)[1]<= canv.coords(ball)[3] <= canv.coords(paddle2)[3]:
        dx = -dx
        if canv.coords(paddle2)[1] <= canv.coords(ball)[1] <= (int((canv.coords(paddle2)[1] + canv.coords(paddle2)[3])) / 2 ):
            dy -= 1
            canv.move(ball, dx, dy)
        elif (int(canv.coords(paddle2)[1] + canv.coords(paddle2)[3])/ 2 ) <= canv.coords(ball)[3] <= canv.coords(paddle2)[3]:
            dy += 1
            canv.move(ball, dx, dy)
        else:
            canv.move(ball, dx, dy)
#     to make ball bounce off roof
    elif canv.coords(ball)[1]<=0:
        dy = -dy
        canv.move(ball, dx, dy)
#        to mkae ball bounce of floor
    elif canv.coords(ball)[1]>=325:
        dy = -dy
        canv.move(ball, dx, dy)
#        if player 2 scores
    elif canv.coords(ball)[2]<=0:
        Player2score += 1
        Player2scoreLabel.configure(text="Score: "+ str(Player2score))
        canv.coords(ball, 300,160,310,170)
        canv.coords(paddle1, 0,200,10,120)
        canv.coords(paddle2, 590,200,600,120)
        dx=2
        dy=0
#        if player1 scores
    elif canv.coords(ball)[0]>=600:
        Player1score += 1
        Player1scoreLabel.configure(text="Score: "+ str(Player1score))
        canv.coords(ball, 300,160,310,170)
        canv.coords(paddle1, 0,200,10,120)
        canv.coords(paddle2, 590,200,600,120)
        dx=-2
        dy=0
#        end game if player 1 wins
    elif Player1score==3:
        dx=0
        dy=0
#        end game if player 2 wins
    elif Player2score==3:
        dx=0
        dy=0
#        move ball if nothign happens
    else:        
        canv.move(ball, dx, dy)
    canv.after(10, moveBall)

#buttons
Butframe = Frame(relief=SUNKEN, width=200, height = 150, background="white")
Butframe.pack()
startButton = Button(Butframe, text="Start", command = startgame)
startButton.pack(side=LEFT)
quitButton = Button(Butframe, text="Quit", command=root.destroy)
quitButton.pack(side=LEFT)

#scores
Score1frame = Frame(relief=SUNKEN, width=200, height = 150, background="white")
Score1frame.pack(side=LEFT)    
Player1scoreLabel = Label(Score1frame, text="Score: "+ str(Player1score), background="green")
Player1scoreLabel.pack()
Score2frame = Frame(relief=SUNKEN, width=200, height = 150, background="white")
Score2frame.pack(side=RIGHT) 
Player2scoreLabel = Label(Score2frame, text="Score: "+ str(Player2score), background="green")
Player2scoreLabel.pack()

#binding of movement keys    
root.bind("<Up>", moveUp2)
root.bind("<w>", moveUp1)
root.bind("<Down>", moveDown2)
root.bind("<s>", moveDown1)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your apparent speed increase is due to **overlapping** calls to the `.after()` method.

When one of the players wins, you should stop the loop in `moveBall()`, for example using a global variable called `gameover` like below:

```
# Initialize gameover variable
gameover = False

# (...) (Reset gameover to False in startgame() as well)

def moveBall():
    global dy, dx, Player1score, Player2score, gameover

    # (...)

    # end game if player 1 or 2 wins
    elif Player1score==3 or Player2score==3:
        dx=0
        dy=0
        gameover = True
    # move ball if nothing happens
    else:        
        canv.move(ball, dx, dy)

    # Repeat until game is over
    if not gameover:
        canv.after(10, moveBall)
```